# OpenGL application crashing

Tags: c, opengl

This OpenGL program is written to draw a triangle and it got crashed.

Basically a set of triangle vertices is define as array named coordinate, then this array is passed to a buffer and the method glDrawArrays will draw the triangle based on the mode GL_TRIANGLES start from vertex 0, 3 vertices in total.

Am I right? And could someone show me where is the error? Here is the code:

```
// Open an OpenGL window
GLFWwindow* window;
int k = 0;

/****Step 1: define vertices in (x, y, z) form****/
const GLfloat coordinates[] = {
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
};
/************************/

/**Step 2: send this triangle vertices to OpenGL through a buffer**/
GLuint vertexBuffer; // identify vertex buffer

void Render(void){
    /************************/
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3 /*size*/, GL_FLOAT /*type*/, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    //glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    /************************/

//    glClearColor(0., 1., 1., 1.); // blue colour
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    // Swap front and back rendering buffers
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    //Poll for and process events
    glfwPollEvents();
}

int main( void ) {
    /*Initializing steps here*/


    // Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context
    window = glfwCreateWindow(700, 500, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);

    // Make the window's context current
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /**Step 2: send this triangle vertices to OpenGL through a buffer**/
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer); // generating 1 buffer, put resulting identifier in this buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(coordinates), coordinates, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    /************************/

    // Main loop
    while( glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0) {
            // OpenGL rendering goes here...
        Render();
    }
    // Close window and terminate GLFW
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    // Exit program
    exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
    }
```

**EDIT**
Here is a screenshot of the output:

[image]

**UPDATE**
I found the error, this is because I create the OpenGL context after initializing GLEW. It causes program to crash.

Comment: Where it crashes? have you checked with the debugger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, first of all you should have provided more details, but I figured them by myself. Here is it:

Missed headers:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

Makefile:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -O2
CFLAGS += $(shell pkg-config --cflags glfw3)
CFLAGS += $(shell pkg-config --cflags glew)
LDFLAGS += $(shell pkg-config --libs glfw3)
LDFLAGS += $(shell pkg-config --libs glew)
SOURCES = main.c
OUT = gl-test
CC = gcc

default: $(SOURCES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(SOURCES) -o $(OUT)

clean:
    -rm -f $(OUT)

.PHONY: default clean
```

Error occured: Segmentation fault, in next command:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
```

But what I see is that **glfwCreateWindow()** returns NULL, so the error is already in very first instruction. You can figure out why this error happend like this:

```
static void error_callback(int error, const char *description)
{
    puts(description);
}

int main(void)
{
    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);
    ...
}
```

And also it worth to modify window creating code to be like that:

```
// Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context
window = glfwCreateWindow(700, 500, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
if (window == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error in glfwCreateWindow\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

After this you can see next output in my terminal:

```
The GLFW library is not initialized
Error in glfwCreateWindow
```

Please try to do the same and confirm that you have the same problem. If no, please provide output from your terminal.

**EDIT 1**:

Ok, it seems like first of all you need to do the next just in the **main()** beginning:

```
if (!glfwInit()) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error on GLWF init\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

It solves previous error, but I still have segmentation fault error.

**EDIT 2**:

Second error is that GLEW wasn't initialized. It seems GLEW init must be put when window is already created, like this:

```
// Make the window's context current
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

glewinit_res = glewInit();
if (glewinit_res != GLEW_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Glew init error: %s\n",
            glewGetErrorString(glewinit_res));
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Now I don't have any runtime errors, window shows up, but it only has black background and nothing on it. Anyway, I believe original error is fixed.

**EDIT 3**:

If you want to see your triangles, just remove **glClear()** function call.

Here is what I see:
[image: screenshot].

Here is modified code that works for me (main.c file):
http://pastebin.com/sx5nMQHc

Comment: You must not use `<stdlib.h>` `<stdio.h>` in C++. Use `<cstdlib>` `<cstdio>` instead.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: I'm not using C++ here, only old good C :) You can see it from my Makefile. This project doesn't use anything from C++, so why use C++ to build it at all?

Comment: I removed those headers stuffs and initializing code and add comments where I put them instead. Just too many uneccessary codes. Anw, thank for the help.

Comment: Please see my EDITs I just added in the end of my answer. If they fix your problem -- please verify my answer as correct one.

Comment: @SamProtsenko Ok. They just looked strange in answer to C++ question. :)